# Access fragment's variable outside the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a single activity, multiple fragments and multiple subview. In some cases I have to access a fragment's variable to which the subview(extends RelativeLayout) is attached. How can I do this?

I can access the views by

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager.getFragmentByTag("TAG").getView().findViewById()
```

But can't access the variables in that fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getFragmentByTag` returns a `Fragment`, try casting the fragment you get back to your implementation's class and then accessing them like so:

```
((MyCustomFragment)getActivity().getFragmentManager.getFragmentByTag("TAG"))
    .getMySuperSecretField();
```

If you post some more details/code, I might be able to diagnose you issue better